# Как зациклить?

Tags: c

Всем доброго времени суток! Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы при вопросе "Корзина пуста?", вводя ответ 2, перекидывало на начало кода, т.е. "Шарик чёрный или белый?".
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

main()
{
      setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
      int wapuk,answer;
      cout<<"Шарик чёрный или белый?: ";
      cin>>wapuk;
      if(wapuk==1)
            cout<<"Положить шарик в корзину для чёрных.";
      else
      {
          if(wapuk==2)
                cout<<"Положить шарик в корзину для белых.";
      }  
      cout<<"\nКорзина пуста??: ";
      cin>>answer;
      if (answer==1)
                    cout<<"Корзина пуста. Работа закончена! :)";
      Else
      {
          If (answer==2) // Вернуться в начало кода
          {

                    }
      }
getch();
}
```

Comment: .

    int answer = 0;
    while (answer != 1) { // цикл закончит работать, когда answer будет равен 1
        ...
        cin >> answer;
    }

Comment: @DrummerIF, самое простое -- **goto**.

А вообще найдите и почитайте какую-нибудь книжку на тему *структурное программирование*.

Началось же, похоже, с [этого](http://khpi-iip.mipk.kharkiv.edu/library/extent/dijkstra/ewd249/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, тег у Вас стоит `C`, а пишите на `C++` (кроме conio.h, кстати, от нее тоже надо избавиться).

Во-вторых, замените `if ... else` на `switch ... case` - будет читабельнее.

Теперь по сути вопроса: чтобы зациклить, нужен цикл (неожиданно, правда?). Но нам нужен не обычный, а бесконечный. Чтобы цикл был бесконечный, его условие, очевидно, должно быть всегда истинно. Мы возьмем `while(1)`. Итого получаем:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Шарик чёрный или белый? ");
    scanf("%d", &wapuk);
    switch (wapuk)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Положить шарик в корзину для чёрных\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Положить шарик в корзину для белых\n");
        default:
            printf("Введите 1 или 2");
            continue; // Переходим к началу цикла
    }
    printf("Корзина пуста? ");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    switch (answer)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Корзина пуста. Работа закончена!");
            return 0; // Выходим
        case 2:
            continue;
        default:
            printf("Введите 1 или 2"); // Пользователь ввел не то, что нам нужно, поэтому начинаем заново. Хотя можно и еще в один бесконечный цикл обернуть, чтобы корректный answer получить.
            continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Я долго пытался сообразить, что такое "вапук"? Охосспадя, это шарик! Я бы за одно только это выгнал Вас из института или школы. Что касается собственно кода, то я бы написал как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* const balls[] = {
    "black",
    "white"
};

const char* const baskets[] = {
    "empty",
    "full"
};

int
input_number(const char* const str, const int min, const int max)
{
    int n;
    do {
        puts(str);
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while( n < min || n > max );
    return n;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int n;
    do {
        n = input_number("Black or white? (1/2)", 1, 2);
        printf("Put the ball in the basket for %s balls.\n", balls[--n]);
        n = input_number("Basket is empty or full? (1/2)", 1, 2);
        printf("Basket is %s\n", baskets[--n]);
    } while( n != 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @VadimTukaev, а как ТС сформулирует свою новую тему здесь, если юзер на вопрос:

     Black or white? (1/2)

вместо циферок введет буковку?

Comment: avp, я не понял смысла Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Смысл в том, что цикл

    int n;
    do {
        puts(str);
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while( n < min || n > max );

начнет работать непредсказуемо (зависит от начального значения `n`, а оно не определено, если `n < min || n > max` выполняется, то зациклится навсегда и т.д.) при неправильном вводе.

--

*Всегда проверяйте результат* `scanf()`.

Comment: Да, действительно, сам же всем это указываю, а тут забыл. Фейспалм. С - очень коварный язык, помните об этом! Собственно, потому я и хочу изучить что-нибудь вроде F#. Надоело придумывать велосипеды на каждый чих.

    while( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < min || n > max );

Кстати, если вводить надо один символ, то можно проще, красивее и надежнее:

    int
    input_symbol(const char* const str, const char* const sym)
    {
        puts(str);
        char* c;
        do {
            c = strchr(sym, getchar());
        } while( !c );
        getchar(); // ловим '\n'
        return c - sym;
    

Comment: А если юзер введет в одной строке строку из нескольких верных символов?

Впрочем, всегда можно сказать, что это *не баг, а фича*.

Кстати, при таком подходе `'\n'` ловить не требуется.

Comment: Уважаемый @VadimTukaev, извините, конечно, и спасибо вам за код, но объясните, пожалуйста, что значат:

    const char* const balls[] =

    input_number(const char* const str, const int min, const int max)
puts(str)

    printf("Put the ball in the basket for %s balls.\n", balls[--n]); //из этого последние слова %s и [--n]

    return 0;

Ещё раз извиняюсь за себя, но я как новичок не понимаю именно этих обозначений. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://nnm-club.me/forum/viewtopic.php?t=216291